# How to find the distribution of cases in the AstraZeneca/Oxford Phase III study interim analysis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to find how the 131 cases from an interim analysis of the AstraZeneca/Oxford Phase III study are distributed among the two arms of two dosing regimens.

Vaccine Efficacy is abbreviated as VE.

Facts from the [AstraZeneca November 23rd Press Release](https://www.astrazeneca.com/media-centre/press-releases/2020/azd1222hlr.html), as I understand them:

- There are two dosing regimens. Let's call them Regimen A and Regimen B.
- Regimen A (2741 participants) has a VE of 90%
- Regimen B (8895 participants) has a VE of 62%
- The combined VE across the two regimens is 70%.
- There were a total of 131 cases in the two regimens.

This is how the [AstraZeneca Phase III Study Protocol](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ctr-med-7111/D8110C00001/52bec400-80f6-4c1b-8791-0483923d0867/c8070a4e-6a9d-46f9-8c32-cece903592b9/D8110C00001_CSP-v2.pdf) defines Vaccine Efficacy (VE):

> "VE is calculated as RRR = 100*(1-relative risk), which is the incidence of infection in the vaccine group relative to the incidence of infection in the control group expressed as a percentage."

**Side Note:** I think they actually made a mistake with the word "relative risk" inside the formula. I think "relative risk" must be "risk ratio". I looked up the notion of "relative risk" and it''s far more complicated than their own description of the formula. The word "risk ratio" I got from [Lesson 3: Measures of Risk - Principles of Epidemiology in Public Health Practice](https://www.cdc.gov/csels/dsepd/ss1978/lesson3/section6.html)

**I updated this question to reflect that the study uses 2:1 randomization. Thanks to Micah for pointing this out to me.**

Furthermore, the protocol states that participants will be randomized in a 2:1 ratio. Two people receiving the vaccine for every one person getting the placebo. I think this done to increase the 'signal', as generally speaking, far less cases of symptomatic covid-19 will be expected in the vaccine group.

> Approximately 30 000 participants will be randomized in a 2:1 ratio to receive 2 IM doses of either 5 × 1010 vp (nominal, ± 1.5 × 1010 vp) AZD1222 (n = approximately 20 000) or saline placebo (n = approximately 10 000) 4 weeks apart, on Days 1 and 29.

I found the following formula to compute vaccine efficacy in [a book chapter called Evaluating Protective Effects of Vaccination](https://courses.washington.edu/b578a/readings/bookchap6.pdf). It makes sense to me, except for the characters in subscript, which probably are defined elsewhere.

[image: Vaccine Efficacy Formula]

We're not speaking of incidence per se, but incidence relative to the amount of people at risk.

Since the vaccine group can be expected to have twice as many people in it, this means twice as many people are at risk. This works out to `VE = 1 - ((V/2)/P) = 1 - (V/(2*P))` , where V is the amount of cases in the vaccine group, and P is the amount of cases in the placebo group.

Given this definition of VE and that there were 131 cases total (`P+V=131`), I think it must follow that there were 49 cases in the vaccine group, and 82 cases in the placebo group, because this is the only proportion that results in a vaccine efficacy of 70%.

`1-(49/(2*82)) = 0.701 = 0.70`

Now the question is, how are these cases (49 in the vaccine group, 82 in the placebo group) spread along the two regimens?

I tried to write down the formulas, as best as I could. I used the following for the variable names:

- `P`: The amount of cases in the placebo group P.
- `V`: The amount of cases in the vaccine group V.
- Three suffixes: `t` for Total, `a` for Regimen A, `b` for Regimen B.

`Pt =  82 = Pa + Pb`
`Vt =  49 = Va + Vb`
`(1-Va/Pa) = 0.90` ---> `Va/Pa = 0.1`
`(1-Vb/Pb) = 0.62` ---> `Vb/Pb = 0.38`

Is this making sense?
Can this be solved?

If so, is there one solution, or multiple solutions?

Thanks in advance!

I found the following solution by trial and error. My guess is it's the only solution, but I don't know for sure.

```
VE A:        1 - (5/(2*24))  = 0.895  = 0.90
VE B:        1 - (44/(2*58)) = 0.6206 = 0.62 
VE Combined: 1 - (49/(2*82)) = 0.701  = 0.70
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are you sure that the two arms of the study have different control groups? It looks like both protocols are "you get two shots a month apart" and the only difference is the dosage, so it seems like they could have designed the study to work with a single control group while still maintaining the blinding.

Comment: I don't seem any information about the two separate vaccine arms in the pdf you posted, but it looks like the protocol calls for twice as many people to receive the vaccine as the placebo. So there were probably 49 cases with the vaccine and 81 with the placebo ($1-49/(2\times 81) \approx 0.6975$).

Comment: @Micah "it looks like the protocol calls for twice as many people to receive the vaccine as the placebo. " good catch! thanks! I totally missed that. I'm pretty sure the Moderna and Pfizer trials use 1:1 randomization and I kinda forgot about Astrazeneca doing it differently. 

I think this changes the formula to changes Vaccine Efficacy!

"Approximately 30 000 participants will be randomized in a 2:1 ratio to receive 2 IM doses of either 5 × 1010 vp (nominal, ± 1.5 × 1010 vp) AZD1222 (n = approximately 20 000) or saline placebo (n = approximately 10 000) 4 weeks apart, on Days 1 and 29."

Comment: @Micah I think you meant `1-(49/(2*81)) = 0.6975`. These would be 49+81=130 cases. There were in fact 131 cases, but `1-(49/(2*82)) = 0.701` . So I think we've got that one down.

Indeed, with my limited understanding of numbers, I'd say with twice as many people in the vaccine group compared to the placebo group, you'd also expect twice as many cases. This needs to be compensated for by dividing by two.

I'll go have a look tomorrow what it means for the other equations.

Comment: @Micah "are you sure that the two arms of the study have different control groups? ". Actually, no. I think in the end my question is based on assumptions. I have the *impression* that they run different 'sub-studies' as a kind of silo, and then combine the results from the different sub-studies ("pooled analysis") to compute the value for their primary endpoint (as well as secondary endpoints, but they are not discussed here).

Comment: The sub-studies analyzed by Oxford are COV002 (a Phase II/III trial in the UK) and COV003 (a Phase III trial in Brazil). This is information taken from the press release. When I look at the rest what they write, it seems like both studies/trials are pretty independent. I think they also have trials in Japan and the US, but they're not part of this analysis by AstraZeneca. Maybe they have two few cases there, or maybe the trials have run for too little time in total.

Answer (score 1):

All the equations are ultimately *linear*. Thus the solution you found must be unique.